Can't login to Ubuntu 24.04 when Yubico key is inserted
I'm unable to log in to my Ubuntu 24.04 system when my Yubico key is inserted. The login process hangs or fails, preventing access to my account. This issue started after upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04, where everything worked fine.
What I've Tried:
I've attempted various fixes that worked in Ubuntu 22.04, including:

Disabling specific PAM modules in /etc/pam.d/
Modifying configurations in /etc/gdm3/
Unfortunately, none of these solutions seem to work on Ubuntu 24.04.

Question:
Has anyone encountered this issue on Ubuntu 24.04? Are there any new steps or configurations that I should be aware of to resolve this problem? Any guidance would be appreciated.

I have also upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 TLS to version 24.04 TLS and I have got the same issue : gdm3 hangs after I touch the Yubikey and enter my password.
My solution was to use lightdm instead of gdm3

Thank you Nicolas. I will go that way.
